# Prolem with for loop and $.get function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

stuck on this issues for hours now... Think it's something to do with using $.get within a loop and its asynchronicity but I cannot figure it out.

This code works if a add a breakpoint through firebug on the $.get line but if I just run it it does not work.

Basically I want to loop through 20 hidden fields when the page loads and set a dropdown list value based on the value

```
for (i = 1; i <= 21; i++) {
        var sMessageTypeID = $('#MessageOrder' + i).val();
        //This line calls the Controller and populates the corresponding MessageType Drop down
        $.get('@Url.Action("GetMessageTypeByMessageTypeID")', { MessageTypeID: sMessageTypeID }, function (data) {
            $('#MessageTypes' + i).val(data);
        });
    };
```

Here is the controller code

```
public JsonResult GetMessageTypeByMessageTypeID(long MessageTypeID)
    {
        tblMessageType tblMessageType = db.tblMessageTypes.Single(t => t.MessageTypeID == MessageTypeID);
        return Json(tblMessageType.MessageType, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Are you waiting for the responses from the server in your test?

Comment: yes, the server is responding

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solution provided by @alex about the closure, I would like to point out that it is a very bad idea to hammer your server with AJAX requests in a loop as you currently do. Imagine multiple users visiting this page. I would recommend you sending the ids in a single AJAX request and adapting the controller action to return an array:

```
var messageIds = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 21; i++) {
    messageIds.push($('#MessageOrder' + i).val());
}

// send a single AJAX request to the controller action:
$.get('@Url.Action("GetMessageTypeByMessageTypeID")', { messageIds: messageIds }, function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#MessageTypes' + (i + 1)).val(data[i]);
    }
});
```

and finally update the controller action so that it handles multiple ids:

```
public ActionResult GetMessageTypeByMessageTypeID(long[] messageIds)
{
    var messageTypes = 
        from t in db.tblMessageTypes
        where messageIds.Contains(t.MessageTypeID)
        select t.MessageType;
    return Json(messageTypes.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I was a little hesitant about the looping.  Just didn't know how else to do it!

Comment: Thanks Darin : Just tried changing to your solution... The var called messageIds seems to be coming through as null to the controller.

Comment: I should add that I CAN see that the var messageIds does contain data before it is passed to the controller

Answer (score 0):

This following line has an anonymous function which closes over its ancestry scope.

```
$.get('@Url.Action("GetMessageTypeByMessageTypeID")', { MessageTypeID: sMessageTypeID }, function (data) {
    $('#MessageTypes' + i).val(data);
});
```

The value of `i` there is most likely the value that terminated the loop (`21`).

You need to break the closure by getting the value passed by value...

```
$.get('@Url.Action("GetMessageTypeByMessageTypeID")', { MessageTypeID: sMessageTypeID }, (function (j) {
    return function(data) { $('#MessageTypes' + j).val(data); };
})(i));
```

Comment: Actually that fixed it - can't really wrap my head around why though. But thanks!

Comment: @Zenacity, if this fixed it and it is your answer, please mark it as such.